# How can I make an entire S3 bucket with about 50,000 files in it public?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I tried using the AWS console, but after making a few 100 files public it errors out on me. Other easy-to-use methods?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make 10,000 files in S3 public](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142388/how-to-make-10-000-files-in-s3-public)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going to have to change the ACL on each resource. You might be able to easily do it with [S3Browser](http://s3browser.com/) or [S3Fox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3247/). There is no  'apply to children' operation.