# Make previously public files private with fog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, fog

I have uploaded files to a aws bucket using fog and carrierwave. All these files have been uploaded as public files (this is apparently default behaviour for fog)

At the moment i do not want any of these files to be public. I have applied the setting: `config.fog_public = false` to make the file private.

However old files that have been uploaded from before are still public. Is it possible make these private?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using an app named [3Hub](http://www.3hubapp.com/). With this app i could simple choose the folder and apply new permissions to all subfolders and files.

However if you want to do this through fog/carrierwave. Checkout this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/carrierwave/f0Icvk34Xjk

I ended up not using this kind of approach, however it looks promising.

Also checkout this alternative solution:
[How to make 10,000 files in S3 public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142388/how-to-make-10-000-files-in-s3-public#answer-7650095)