# How to give public access for some specific file in amazon S3 bucket during upload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Currently I am using a S3 bucket to upload some pdfs.

Now none of those pdfs are directly accessible via url. But I want to make some specific pdfs public during upload.

I have gone [this](https://havecamerawilltravel.com/photographer/how-allow-public-access-amazon-bucket) blog which explains how to make all the resources in a bucket public. But I do not want this, I want only few specific files to be public during upload.

Currently I am using ruby aws-sdk. I want to know is this possible?

Comment: this can give you some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142388/how-to-make-10-000-files-in-s3-public?rq=1

Comment: Can you please share a code snippet you tried to use ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't paste any specific code snippet you use, I assume you atr trying to achieve this using official [AWS Ruby SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#put_object-instance_method)

```
File.open('/source/file/path', 'rb') do |file|
  s3.put_object(bucket: 'bucket-name', key: 'object-key', body: file)
end
```

By default, any uploaded file is private, therefore not accessible by URL.

If you want to make it public, additional param needs to be set: `acl: "public-read"`. By default, all AWS SDKs are using ACL `private`. So modifying my last example, it will look like:

```
File.open('/source/file/path', 'rb') do |file|
  s3.put_object(acl: "public-read", bucket: 'bucket-name', key: 'object-key', body: file)
end
```

Now you should be able to access your file by URL.

You can read more about canned ACLs on S3 here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl