# S3 Bucket objects access denied for existing one

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I had configured my bucket with public access to all my objects

But older files is still not public.
If i access my old objects i'm getting access denied.
I have to manually change them to public no other option for me.Currently i have 5000 objects inside my bucket.Manually changing them is not possible
Is there any other thing to change in my bucket configuration from the default one..

Comment: Why don't you select all and make public ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aws cli command to achieve that.Use [aws s3api put-object-acl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-object-acl.html).

Description :

> uses the acl subresource to set the access control list (ACL)
>   permissions for an object that already exists in a bucket.

Be aware that the put-object-acl command is for a single object only. In case you want to run it recursively, take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46572744/how-to-change-permission-recursively-to-folder-with-aws-s3-or-aws-s3api).

More about [How can I grant public read access to some objects in my Amazon S3 bucket?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket/)