# Fix ACL of all objects in one S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, acl

I have 15,000 files in S3 and they have wrong ACL permissions. The owner of the objects is an external AWS account. I'm looking for a way to change this as quickly as possible. I ran [antoligy/s3-recursive-acl: A tool for bulk-updating ACL in Amazon S3](https://github.com/antoligy/s3-recursive-acl) but when I run it I get this:

> s3-recursive-acl.go: command not found

When I use sudo:

> sudo: ./s3-recursive-acl.go: command not found

when I do install `go`:

```
go install s3-recursive-acl.go
s3-recursive-acl.go:9:2: cannot find package "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws (from $GOROOT)
        /home/souad/go/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws (from $GOPATH)
s3-recursive-acl.go:10:2: cannot find package "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session (from $GOROOT)
        /home/souad/go/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session (from $GOPATH)
s3-recursive-acl.go:11:2: cannot find package "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3 (from $GOROOT)
        /home/souad/go/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3 (from $GOPATH)
```

Please any ideas because I've pretty much tried everything.

Comment: take a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/58504030/9931092

Comment: Yes  I have used the python script mentioned in there but it is not very efficient

Comment: this is not python its aws cli.

Comment: the awscli command is for one single file only. I have thousands of files

Comment: in my answer, I point to other thread which explains how to use other aws CLI commands in order to run the ACL command recursively.

Comment: yeah the problem of using aws cp is that it copies a new version of the file it doesn't just change the object acl

Comment: @Souad It is not possible to change the ACL on an object. However, if the object is copied to itself, the ACL can be changed during the copy. This an be done as a [bulk update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46577516/174777).