# AWS S3 change an entire folder inside a bucket from public to private with CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I've been trying to change all the files inside a folder to private without success. I want to use CLI because I am not a coder and I tried this code without success:

`s3cmd setacl --acl-private --recursive s3://bucket-name/folder1/folder2/`

And I am getting a "command not found". Any insights on this?

Comment: You have to install `s3cmd` to your machine first. See https://s3tools.org/download. But if you are not familiar with command line and alternatively with official AWS CLI, I would suggest to use AWS S3 Batch Operations in the console. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops-operations.html and section called "Replace access control list".

Comment: Any way I can do it directly on AWS Cloud Shell CLI?

Comment: I want to do it directly on AWS Cloud Shell CLI, not sure if that's the right command but if not I'm trying to find it.

Comment: You can't do this with a single API command. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46572744/how-to-change-permission-recursively-to-folder-with-aws-s3-or-aws-s3api fir some options

Comment: Side-question: Why do you wish to recursively set the ACL to private? Objects in Amazon S3 are private by default, so this activity would only be necessary if objects were previously set to a different ACL (eg ACL=public).

Comment: Because I uploaded them as public, then I want to change them back to private.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the AWS Cloud Shell code for listing all objects in a bucket folder and making them private:

```
aws s3 ls --recursive s3://<bucket_name>/<folder_name> | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f4- | awk '{print $NF}' | while read line; do echo "$line"; aws s3api put-object-acl --acl private --bucket <bucket_name> --key "$line"; done;
```

If you want to first see which files will be affected, you can simply remove the `put-object-acl` from the code:

```
aws s3 ls --recursive s3://<bucket_name>/<folder_name> | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f4- | awk '{print $NF}' | while read line; do echo "$line"; done;
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try with few steps to set the ACL of S3 objects to private using `s3cmd`**:

**Install**: Install the `s3cmd` tool using your system's package manager (like, `brew` or `apt`).

**Configure**: Run `s3cmd --configure` to set up your AWS credentials.

**Verify Configuration**: Check your configuration with `s3cmd ls` to ensure it's working.

**Set ACL to Private**: Run the command to make objects in a specific `S3` folder private:

```
s3cmd setacl --acl-private --recursive s3://bucket-name/folder1/folder2/
```