# Set ACL to private on all the files in a folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

For the testing purpose I have uploaded 'n'- number of files to a folder in the s3 bucket as "any aws user" ACL. Now I want to change ACL to "private" for all the files in that folder. I find that it can be done more easily by a third-party tool called s3cmd. But I have no permission to use third party tools. So is there any way to do it by the aws console(other than doing it programtically iterating over each file and setting the ACL).I am using php api's, Or is there any way to set acl recursively through AWS cli

Answer (score 0):

You can Refer to this [AWS CLI Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-acl.html) using `put-bucket-acl` the adding `--acl to private`

Alternatively you can specify with bucket policy to enforce private access to bucket:
`{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
  {
   "Sid": "PrivateAclPolicy",  "Effect": "Deny",
   "Principal": { "AWS": "*"},
   "Action": [
    "s3:PutObject",
    "s3:PutObjectAcl"
   ],
   "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/foldername/*"
   ],
   "Condition": {
    "StringNotEquals": {
     "s3:x-amz-acl": [
      "private"
     ]
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}`

Replace bucket_name and foldername with the name of your bucket and folder.

Thanks

Comment: adding acl private to the bucket will not make the existing keys private. If we apply put-object-acl it need to be done induvidually to each file. I have referd  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142388/how-to-make-10-000-files-in-s3-public and tried with sync a bucket to itself but that also make any sense

Comment: The problem is that I have added the bucket policy as you mentioned, it works correctly for newly added files. But it does not applicable to existing keys. I have some files with "authenticated user" acl which can be accessed from any aws account. Which is a security threat.