# Exclude one Amazon S3 object from a Bucket Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to cancel the public access permission of a file(`images/login_logo.png`) inside my S3 bucket `my-test-bucket`.

Currently, this file's permission setting is as the following:

[image]

As you can see in the above picture. It has no public access for everyone.

But I can still access it from the s3 link.

Is this phenomenon caused by my bucket policy?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1528702071704",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1528702067249",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-test-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

If so, what's the best way to cancel the public access permission of a single file inside a large public bucket which contains about 10,000 files?

I cannot apply `make public` to a large bucket due to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142388/how-to-make-10-000-files-in-s3-public).

Comment: Yes, you bucket policy allows reads for everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, all objects in Amazon S3 are private.

You can make an object accessible via a **Bucket Policy** (such as yours above), or by adding **permissions on the specific object**.

If *either* of these methods grant access to an object, then the object is accessible. So, the fact that your bucket policy is granting access to the entire bucket means that your object is public.

The only way to make an exception for one file would be to **add a Deny policy**, such as:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1528702071704",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowALl",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-test-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyOneObject",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-test-bucket/images/login_logo.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

A *Deny* always overrides an *Allow*, so that object will remain private.

However, be careful: This policy is denying read access to *everybody* (including *you!*). You will probably need to tweak it so that you can still get access (probably by using `NotPrincipal`).

Comment: Thank you for your help :-)