# Public access for Active Storage in Rails 6.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I use Active Storage on my Rails site with AWS. After upgrading to 6.1, I'd like to configure public access per [the guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#public-access) so my images have permanent URLs.

I've determined that I need to keep the existing service as-is so previously uploaded images continue to work. I've created a new service and configured the app to use it [like this](https://github.com/JasonBarnabe/greasyfork/pull/840/files).

Previous images continue to work like this, but new image uploads result in Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied. Note that the credentials used are exactly the same as in the previous, working, non-public service. The guide mentions that the bucket needs to have the proper permissions, but not what exactly needs to be set.

Looking in AWS, the section "Block public access (bucket settings)" is all set to "Off". In "Access control list (ACL)", "Bucket owner (your AWS account)" has "List, Write" for both "Objects" and "Bucket ACL". No other permissions are listed. I've tried changing "Everyone (public access)" to include "List" for "Objects" and "Read" for "Bucket ACL" - doesn't seem to solve the problem.

How do I get public URLs working with Active Storage?

Comment: if you are using "aws-sdk-s3" gem then you need to add following permissions: `s3:ListBucket`, `s3:PutObject`, `s3:GetObject`, and `s3:DeleteObject`.

Comment: did you check with aws cli tool that s3 bucket is accessible you can list objects in it

Comment: I do use aws-sdk-s3. Where/how can I check the permissions? (I've listed what I see in the UI in the question.) `aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket mybucketname` lists the objects successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The permission you need when switching from private access to public is `PutObjectAcl`. Adding this in the [IAM Management Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#/users) makes it work.

In addition, rather than creating a new service, you can mark all images in the existing service as public-readable via the UI or [via a script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31379500/615385).