# How do I make all files in an S3 bucket public?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My S3 Bucket was private. But now I have updated it to be public. I still can't seem to access the files without signing the URL etc. How do I make all of them public?

Comment: Duplicate. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129595/how-can-i-make-an-entire-s3-bucket-with-about-50-000-files-in-it-public & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142388/how-to-make-10-000-files-in-s3-public

Comment: @kaliatech the first one is wrong ("you can't do it except on every object"). The second is correct ("add a policy").

Comment: @tedder42 I believe it depends on how policy/permissions were setup on the bucket/objects. (IAM vs. S3 vs ACL). OP didn't say, so I linked both posts. For more info: [IAM policies and Bucket Policies and ACLs!](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/TxPOJBY6FE360K/IAM-policies-and-Bucket-Policies-and-ACLs-Oh-My-Controlling-Access-to-S3-Resourc)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**AWS Console**

To make all objects in a bucket publicly readable, create a Bucket Policy on that specific bucket, which grants `GetObject` permissions for anonymous users. Replace `examplebucket` with the name of the bucket. You can add the Bucket Policy in the Amazon S3 Management Console, in the Permissions section.

```
{
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid": "AddPerm",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

**AWS CLI/Terminal**

Create a bucket policy file in your computer named say, `my-bucket-policy.json`. Replace `examplebucket` with the name of the bucket:

```
{
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid": "AddPerm",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

And then apply the policy via your terminal using the command:

```
aws s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket examplebucket --policy file://my-bucket-policy.json
```